# how to put a field-separator in Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple

Tags: perl

The following code works well for me, but I am not able to figure out how to separate columns with a field-separator like comma (,) character.

Please advise, thanks.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple;

my @data;
my $xls = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Simple->read('mylargefile.xls');
foreach my $sheet ($xls->sheets) {
     while ($sheet->has_data) {  
         @data = $sheet->next_row;
         print "@data \n";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since @data is an array of cells, you can use the built-in join() function like so:

```
print join(',', @data);
```

Or replace the comma with a separator of your choice.